# Чтение нормалей из OBJ файла

Tags: opengl, obj

Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить:
В моем простом obj файле куба есть координаты вершин и нормалей. Если взять, к примеру первую поверхность, то она состоит из вершин 1, 3, 5 и 7, которые лежат на плоскости Y. Вопрос в том, что нормаль, которая указана к этим вершинам, направлена параллельно плоскости Y, а не перпендикулярно, как должно быть
Наверное, я где-то туплю :)

```
a# Blender v3.0.0 OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib untitledggg.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.625000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.500000
vt 0.875000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 0.750000
vt 0.375000 0.750000
vt 0.625000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 1.000000
vt 0.375000 0.000000
vt 0.625000 0.000000
vt 0.625000 0.250000
vt 0.375000 0.250000
vt 0.125000 0.500000
vt 0.375000 0.500000
vt 0.125000 0.750000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1/1/1 5/2/1 7/3/1 3/4/1
f 4/5/2 3/4/2 7/6/2 8/7/2
f 8/8/3 7/9/3 5/10/3 6/11/3
f 6/12/4 2/13/4 4/5/4 8/14/4
f 2/13/5 1/1/5 3/4/5 4/5/5
f 6/11/6 5/10/6 1/1/6 2/13/6
```

Comment: я загрузил этот куб в блендер и нормали показывает корректно.

Comment: Да, но я пытаюсь прочитать файл на с++ в opengl, и мне нужно понять как это сделать

Comment: Возможно потому, что нормали относятся не просто к вершинам, а к вершинам, которые принадлежат граням. Поэтому, когда пишите "нормали к вершине 1" - это лишено смысла.

Comment: Согласен, но опять же, если взять первую грань, то ее вершины расположены на плоскости Y, и нормаль этой грани направлена параллельно ей

Comment: точки 1 5 7 3, то у них одна и та же y координата, поэтому они находятся в плоскости XY, а вектор нормали как раз направлен паралельно с осью y (в положительном направлении). Быть в плоскости Y -  невозможно - плоскость определяется двумя линиями/отрезками или отрезком и точкой.

Comment: Понял, что-то я реально затупил. Спасибо большое!